# why does my object keep stretching when i rotate it

Tags: modifiers, objects, armature, edit-mode

[image]

I was doing some project from my school and i neeed to make a 3d model of an infinity mirror. So im still very new to blender. While i was following the tutorials i need to rotate my object, and its always dragging that long thing. I already search for the solve of this for like 30 minutes and can't found any answer.

Comment: Some before and after photos would help. Also, don’t delete the extra blank line between your text and the image URL at the bottom. That makes the image display not work.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have not selected the vertices behind each element of the mesh, as a result they're being left behind and the faces between them and the selected are getting heavily stretched.

The solution is to either do your selection in Wireframe mode (<kbd>z</kbd>) or run Select Linked (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>) to also select the rear verts

Comment: thankyou so much, i tried to follow ur guides and it works now :D